# Was there any difference between using regex in java and regex in javascript?

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement to build a regex pattern to validate a String in Java. Hence I build a pattern
`[A-Z][a-z]*\s?[A-Z]?[a-z]*$` for the conditions:

- Should start with caps
- Every other Word should start with caps
- No numbers included
- no consecutive two spaces allowed

`Pattern.matches("[A-Z][a-z]*\s?[A-Z]?[a-z]*$","Joe V")`  returns `false` for me in java.
But the same pattern returns true for the data "Joe V" in regexr.com.

What might be the cause?

Comment: Are you sure about `s?`, it seems you expect that to match a space..., but that would need to be `\s?`, and in a string literal with escaped backslash...

Comment: Yeah, you're right. that was misspelled one.

Comment: But still didn't escape that backslash -- because of the Java string literal it is in.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has native support for regex while Java doesn't. Since Java uses `\` for special signs in strings (like `\n`) you have to escape the `\` to actually be a `\` sign. That's done with another `\`. So any `\` you use in Java  should be written as `\\`.

Thus your regex / code should be:

```
Pattern.matches("[A-Z][a-z]*\\s?[A-Z]?[a-z]*$", "Joe V")
```

which returns `true`

P.s. `\s` is interpreted as a Space in any Java-String

Comment: `\s` being interpreted as a space is a recent addition (Java 15, when text blocks where released)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Pattern.matches("[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\\s[A-Z][a-z]*)*","Joe V")
Pattern.matches("\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}*(?:\\s\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}*)*","Joe V")
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/FqkEpu/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/FqkEpu/2).

Note that `.matches` requires a full string match, hence the use of `^` and `$` anchors on the testing site and their absence in the code.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string (implied in `.matches`)
- `[A-Z]` / `\p{Lu}` - an (Unicode) uppercase letter
- `[a-z]*` / `\p{Ll}*` - zero or more (Unicode) lowercase letters
- `(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]*)*` / `(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\s` - one whitespace
  - `[A-Z][a-z]*` /`\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*` - an uppercase (Unicode) letter and then zero or more (Unicode) lowercase letters.
- `$` - end of string (implied in `.matches`)